# clearRect with fade to transparent

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I've drawn some shapes to my transparent canvas.

Lots of animated circles to be precise.

I would like to fade the bottom edge of my canvas to fully transparent, from transparent (but with the shapes).

**Edit**

See the image below; I'm after the effect on the right, as opposed to what I currently have which is a cut in half circle using `clearRect()`

[image]

Anyone have an ideas?

Comment: Can you point to an image or something that shows what you're after?

Comment: give me 5 minutes @Matt, I'll knock something up

Comment: @Matt I've just edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a gradient with alpha in it (using `rgba()` syntax) and apply it to the stroke. Something like:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, canvas.height);
gradient.addColorStop(0,"#f00");
gradient.addColorStop(0.75,"rgba(255, 0, 0, 0)");
ctx.strokeStyle = gradient;

ctx.lineWidth = 10;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(150, 150, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2);
ctx.stroke();
```

Here's a quick demo for it: http://codepen.io/codingcampbell/pen/wMeowa

Changing the `0.75` value in `addColorStop` is what would affect where the alpha part of the gradient comes in. Animating it might be tricky, I *think* you need to create a new gradient for each stop value because you can't modify existing stops (but you *can* keep those gradients in memory and share them with all your shapes)

Comment: Brilliant, thanks @Matt, this was exactly what I was after! I never thought of applying a gradient directly to the stroke!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to make a small vertical gradient and apply it as an eraser on the full circle. To make the effect that it's being animated, just move it upwards on every frame (and start from below the circle).